# Matplotlib Darker Background in 3D Plot

Tags: matplotlib

I am plotting the following image in matplotlib.
My problem is that, the image looks good like this, however, I would like to make the background darker, as when I print this image, the grayscale part does not appear in the print. Could someone tell me API to make this change?

I use simple API to plot the 3D curve -

```
ax.plot(X1, Y1, Z1, '^', c='r')
ax.plot(X2, Y2, Z2, 'o', c='b')
```

[image]

What I also tried is this -

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d',  axisbg='gray')
```

This changes the color to dark gray, but it is also changing the colour outside the image -

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I achieved it by using following code -

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
plt.gca().patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax.w_xaxis.set_pane_color((0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0))
ax.w_yaxis.set_pane_color((0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0))
ax.w_zaxis.set_pane_color((0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Matplotlib's dark background [style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/style_sheets/dark_background.html), which uses white for elements that are typically black (text, borders, etc)

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.style.use('dark_background')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

L = 6
x = np.linspace(0, L)
ncolors = len(plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])
shift = np.linspace(0, L, ncolors, endpoint=False)
for s in shift:
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + s), 'o-')
ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_title("'dark_background' style sheet")

plt.show()
```